# How to calibrate cassandra-stress graph option?

Tags: database, graph, cassandra, cassandra-stress

I managed to run stress tool outside the cluster. 
I a;ready have basic table bank_transactions in bank keyspace on my cassa cluster.

bank.bank_transactions (
    customerid text,
    year int,
    month int,
    id timeuuid,
    amount int,
    card text,
    status text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((customerid, year, month), id)
);
This is my profile yaml file:

```
table: bank_transactions

columnspec:
  - name: customerid
    size: uniform(5..10)
    population: uniform(1..10)
  - name: year
    size: fixed(4)
  - name: month
    size: fixed(2)
  - name: timeuuid
    cluster: uniform(20..40)
  - name: amount
    size: uniform(0..1000000)
  - name: text
    size: uniform(10..15)
  - name: status
    size: uniform(10..20)

insert:
    # How many partition to insert per batch
  partitions: fixed(2)
    # How many rows to update per partition
  select: fixed(1)/500
    # UNLOGGED or LOGGED batch for insert
  batchtype: UNLOGGED

queries:
   customer:
      cql: select *  from bank_transactions where customerid = ? and year = ? and month = ? and id = ?
      fields: multirow
#com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: 
#Partition key parts: year, month, id, customerid must be restricted as other parts are
   transactions:
      cql: select customerid, amount, card, status, id from bank_transactions where id = ? and customerid = ? and year = ? and month = ? 
      fields: samerow
   regularupdate:
      cql: update bank_transactions set amount = ? where customerid = ? and year = ? and month = ? and id = ?
      fields: samerow
#nestihalo se v casovem limitu, lze navysit pamet, casovy limit...      
#   updatewithlwt:
#      cql: update bank_transactions set amount = ? where customerid = ? and year = ? and month = ? and id = ? IF status = ?
#      fields: samerow
```

I run my stress

```
./cassandra-stress user profile=./stress_transactions.yaml ops\(insert=3,customer=3,transactions=2,regularupdate=1\) \
n=10000 -node 172.16.20.104,172.16.20.105,172.16.20.106 -port native=9042 thrift=9160 jmx=7199 -graph file=./transactions.html
```

I was expecting to have something like graph on cassandra.apache site
[image: exapmle stress graph]

But the result is really weird:
[image: my stress graph result]

Could you please help me, what is going wrong?

P.S. Do not mind distributions and so on, it is just playground...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another playtime, I set n=1000000 (no other change) and the result is much better.
[image: test stress cassandra n=1000000]

Hope it might help to someone ;)